# How to remove only numbers from string

Tags: r, regex

I have following dataframe in R

```
ID     Village_Name     
1      23
2      Name-23
3      34
4      Vasai2
5      23
```

I only want to remove numbers from Village_Name, my desired dataframe would be

```
ID     Village_Name     
1      Name-23
2      Vasai2
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: Is `1e6` a number or a string according to your logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to match one or more numbers from the start (`^`) till the end (`$`) of the numbers and negate (`!`) it so that all numbers only elements become FALSE and others TRUE

```
i1 <- !grepl("^[0-9]+$", df1$Village_Name)
df1[i1, ]
```

Based on the OP's post, it could be also

```
data.frame(ID = head(df1$ID, sum(i1)), Village_Name = df1$Village_Name[i1])
#   ID Village_Name
#1  1      Name-23
#2  2       Vasai2
```

---

Or another option is to convert to numeric resulting in non-numeric elements to be NA and is changed to a logical vector with `is.na`

```
df1[is.na(as.numeric(df1$Village_Name)),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `sub`:

```
df1[nchar(sub("\\d+", "", df1$Village_Name)) > 0, ]
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to strip off all digits from the `Village_Name` column, then assert that there is at least one character remaining, which would imply that the entry is not entirely numerical.

But, I would probably go with the `grepl` option given by @akrun in practice.